# Import .BAK in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Is there any way to import .BAK file in Power BI?

I have backup of SQL Server data and want to import it in to Power BI.
If, in case, it is not possible, than how can I import the SQL Server data to Power BI without any connection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely [not feasible.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Is-it-possible-to-connect-to-a-BAK-file/m-p/169659). To make use of of a .BAK file, you need to restore it to a SQL Server.

Generally, directly connecting to the server is the best option but if that's not possible in your situation, you can export your database to a format like CSV or XLSX that Power BI *can* easily read.

Comment: Short and informative. Thanks @Alexis Olson